# Write log file using org.apache.commons.logging

Tags: java, apache-commons-logging

I'm writing an application where I need to write log to a file using `org.apache.commons.logging` library, but i don't know how to start.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks & best regards.

Comment: Any reason why you want to use apache commong logging? I think you are better of using slf4j instead.

Answer (score 20):

Try this sample, first you need two properties files likes this;

**commons-logging.properties** that put in your application's classpath. The contents of this file should look like:

```
    org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger
```

You can also use Log4j logger besides Jdk14Logger.And need second custom properties file.For example **log-config.properties** looks like this:

```
    # The following creates two handlers
    handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
    # Set the default logging level for the root logger
    .level=SEVERE
    # log level for the "com.example" package
    sample.logging.level=FINE
    # Set the default logging level
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=FINE
    # Set the default formatter
    java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
    # Specify the location and name of the log file
    java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=D:/temp/log/test.log
```

This is sample test class

```
     public class TestLog {

     private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TestLog.class);
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          log.info("Testing Info Message.");
              if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                  log.debug("Testing Debug Message.");
          }
        }
     }
```

This is sample package structure using eclipse;

[image]

And add TestLog class's Edit Configuration under VM arguments likes this;

```
  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/D:/dev/workspace/LoggingTest/bin/log-config.properties(your properties file path)
```

[image]

And run then you can find your log file under D:/temp/log/test.log

Comment: hi @Sai Ye , please instruct me how to put commons-logging.properties in your application's classpath .

I try this,but it still not working.Should I go to TestLog class folder and run command line or not?

Comment: @KhanhQuach I edited log-config.properties and others.Check my edited post.You can try this with eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps... this is how we have done in our project...

A. Include the jar in your project.

B. Define log4j.xml for loggers definition something like this...

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">

    <appender name="FILE" class="org.jboss.logging.appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <errorHandler class="org.jboss.logging.util.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
    <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/server.log"/>
    <param name="Append" value="false"/>
    <param name="MaxFileSize" value="1048576KB"/>
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="3"/>

 <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
   <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n"/>
 </layout>      
</appender>

<root>
   <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
   <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

C. Use the logger in the class:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

Class YourClass{
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(YourClass.class);

    public void yourMethod(){
        log.info("Your Message");
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
D. Since we have a JBoss AS environment so the application is configured to read log4j.xml like following (You would need an equivalent config):

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.logging.Log4jService"
  name="jboss.system:type=Log4jService,service=Logging"
  xmbean-dd="resource:xmdesc/Log4jService-xmbean.xml">
  <attribute name="ConfigurationURL">resource:jboss-log4j.xml</attribute>
  <!-- Set the org.apache.log4j.helpers.LogLog.setQuiteMode. As of log4j1.2.8
  this needs to be set to avoid a possible deadlock on exception at the
  appender level. See bug#696819.
  -->
  <attribute name="Log4jQuietMode">true</attribute>
  <!-- How frequently in seconds the ConfigurationURL is checked for changes -->
  <attribute name="RefreshPeriod">60</attribute>
</mbean>
```

Comment: That is only if you use log4j as the backend for commons logging.

Comment: I tried this , but it not works !
It seem to be that org.apache.commons.logging didn't read log4j file I define

Comment: Yes. We can use log4j and apache commons logging together.