# If fail-> log in text file

Tags: java

I want to log failed entry in a text file.

```
 }else System.out.println("not found!");    

 //Enter entry(log it) in a txt file.
```

How should I go about doing this simply without creating a method?

EDIT:I mean if method is better, then suggestions?

Comment: you can use java.util.logging.Logger

Comment: You can redirect System.out and System.err to a file.

Answer (score 5):

The best thing to do would be to set up a logging framework.  You've got [JUL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950557/good-examples-using-java-util-logging), [log4j](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_sample_program.htm), [commons-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815642/write-log-file-using-org-apache-commons-logging), [slf4j](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/5/Hello-World-Example-of-Simple-Logging-Facade-for-Java-or-SLF4J), etc. as options.  It will take a long time relative to the time I can see you want to spend doing this, but it will be a good investment and it is the "right way to do this".  BTW, I recommend slf4j over the others.

That said, you asked for an easy way to do this without creating a method.  You can [FileUtils.writeStringToFile](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) for this.  Here's an example that works the way you want and compiles, you just need to make sure FileUtils is in your classpath:

```
package com.sandbox;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("out.txt"), "not found!", "UTF8");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say use FileUtils.writeStringToFile w/o creating a method, what do you mean?

Comment: @user2475261 If you include `FileUtils` in your classpath, you can just say what I've written above (let me edit my answer to show you an example)

Answer (score 2):

You could use one of the many logging frameworks available, like http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/ for example

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to download any external logging framework you can use java default logging framework that is in `java.util.logging` package [package description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/logging/package-summary.html)

To log in a file you have to set a proper handler.

```
Handler handler = new FileHandler("logHerePath.log", LOG_SIZE, LOG_ROTATION_COUNT);
Logger.getLogger("").addHandler(handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

If possible in environment etc. you can make a simple Singleton Pattern with a Printwriter that logs the entry.

Then it is only 1 call.

```
MyLogger.log("my entry\n");
```

Comment: You might wish to elaborate on this answer a bit.