# Make org.apache.commons.logging write to file

Tags: java, maven, log4j

I'm using Kinesis Client Library and it uses org.apache.commons.logging. Currently it prints all things on terminal. I want to let logs be written in a file instead.

I found this question [Write log file using org.apache.commons.logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815642/write-log-file-using-org-apache-commons-logging/11823442) and tried to follow the steps. But I didn't see my log files in my specified path.

Here's what I've done:

First, I added two config files `commons-logging.properties` and `log4j.properties` in `consumer/src` folder. My `TestLog.java` file is in `consumer/src/java`.

In commons-logging.properties file:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log = org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger
```

In log4j.properties file:

```
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler, java.util.logging.FileHandler
.level=SEVERE
sample.logging.level=FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.FileHandler.level=ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=/Users/XXX/src/MyKinesis/firstlog
```

And here's my TestLog.java file

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

```
public class TestLog {

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TestLog.class);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Testing Info Message.");
        if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
            System.out.println("HERE");
            log.debug("Testing Debug Message.");
        }
    }
}
```

And I executed this by

`mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="TestLog" -Djava.util.logging.config.file=~/src/MyKinesis/stockStream/src/log4j.properties`

( `~/src/MyKinesis/stockStream/src/log4j.properties` is the path where I stored the log4j.properties file)

But I didn't find the the log file at `/Users/XXX/src/MyKinesis/firstlog`. And also there's no output in the console. Why is that?

Any suggestions will be appreciated!!

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474646/how-to-write-to-a-text-file-using-to-log4j possibly help?

Comment: @ ZeldaZach Yes thanks! I found that I should have put the two config files into the resources folder instead of the src folder. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with your project!!