# How to create a LogFile and path with LoggerFactory

Tags: java, logfile, loggerfactory

EDIT This is my batchfile code to run a (.bat) File , and i try to convert the output of the bat into a Logfile ,but i dont want to set the name of the logfile automatically , for every bat i want to run , create a new logfile with a the name of the BatFile. Hope i could explain it well

```js
   private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BatchFile.class);

    public void BatchFile(File file) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(file.getAbsolutePath());
        processBuilder.directory(file.getParentFile());
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
        try (PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\my_log.log"))) {
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String outputLine = scanner.nextLine();
                LOGGER.info(outputLine);
                out.print(outputLine);
            }

            scanner.close();
        }

        System.out.println(process.waitFor());
    }


}
```

i would like to know if someone had the same problem.
I try to use LoggerFactory to create LogFile for my program, for example:

I want to take the output of System.out.printl  into a LogFile.
Or printing all Errors or messages from console into the LogFile.
Is it even possible?

Thanks

```js
 final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NameOfClass.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible and the purpose of any Logging Framework. I assume you are using Slf4j interfaces. Depending on the implementation have a look at the following getting started guides:

- [log4j](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/log4j/log4j-2-getting-started-example/)
- [logback](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/using-slf4j-with-logback-tutorial.html)
- [commons-logging](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/slf4j/slf4j-commons-logging-example/)

All of them have the option to write your Log Events to files:

- [FileAppender in Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358836/log4j-how-to-configure-simplest-possible-file-logging)
- [FileAppender in Logback](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#FileAppender)
- [FileHandler in commons-logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11815642/write-log-file-using-org-apache-commons-logging)

Comment: thanks for the answer but those are no help , they arent working for me , just one of those has an example for creating a file and this isnt working ...

Comment: Edited my post. But first you need to understand how a logging framework works in general, thats why you need to know the basics, that are described in the first links provided.